# Yarn Hangs on add package

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Yarn add hangs at fetching packages and I have no feedback information about causes.
I looked at this issue [Completely hung when installing example project](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1144) but I found no solution.

[image]

EDIT: this is the my repo [itp-automation-system](https://github.com/pincia/itp-mobile-automation) and the issue comes when I try to add a local package with:

```
yarn add c:/ionic/angular-laravel-echo.zip
```

this is the package-> [angular-
laravel-echo](https://ufile.io/tk9kbj9g)

I updated yarn, node and git, my actual config is:

```
OS@Windows 10

node@10.15.3

yarn@1.15.2
```

Comment: What's the link to your repo, so I can look into it. Without any code it is totally impossible to help.

Comment: Ok...more information added to the post. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to install it with `npm`? Just to exclude the issue is with the package itself.

Comment: @Adriano Yes with npm the installation ends right.